# DateFormat.jm() outputs the same as DateFormat.Hm(), is this a bug?

Tags: flutter, dart, locale

According to the docs for the dart intl package, `DateFormat.jm()` is for formatting time as AM and PM, and `DateFormat.Hm()` is for using the 24 hour format:

> DateFormat.jm()                  -> 5:08 PM
> DateFormat.Hm()                  -> 17:08 // force 24 hour time

However, after configuring Intl to use the user's locale by calling `await findSystemLocale()`, I don't see any difference between the two:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';

...

await findSystemLocale();  // <-- running this causes the problem
final now = DateTime.now();
print("${Intl.defaultLocale} ${DateFormat.jm().format(now)} ${DateFormat.Hm().format(now)}");
```

Gives me:

> en_GB 16:45 16:45

If I omit `await findSystemLocale();` I get the expected result, but in the default locale:

> en_US 5:51 PM 17:51

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the docs?

I'm using intl v0.16.1.

Comment: I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/421

Answer (score 0):

Hm... in my case I have a below result.

```
flutter 1.22.5
intl 0.16.1
```

```
en_US 4:45 PM 16:45
```

If that, how about you use custom format like below?

```
DateFormat('h:mm a').format(now)
```

Comment: Thanks for sanity checking me. I think I figured out what's going wrong: when my app starts up, I set the locale to the device's locale using `findSystemLocale()`. It seems that running the `findSystemLocale()` function causes the problem. I've updated my question. Does this seem like a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
final now = DateTime.now();
  var time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
  print(time);
```

[image]

```
final now = DateTime.now();
  var time = DateFormat.Hm().format(now);
  print(time);
```

[image]